# Hide or obfuscate real path name of webpack chunk files

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm using the vue-cli 2.9.6 on my project and I've noticed that the chunks has the original file path. I mean the path of my computer... how can I hide this? I've tried some options, but I'm not sure if this is related to the devtool or not...

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

The main problem is when you import dynamically any component in your router, for example:

```
component: () => import('@/components/MyComponent');
```

And you make the build. (npm run build), webpack generates some chunk file like 1.d84b8a9dc95989bba08f.js.

With this content:

```
webpackJsonp([4],{"/dHQ":function(n,e,t){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0});var i,l,s,a,o,r,c=t("lvAu"),d=t("gD1p"),u=(i="/Users/myuser/Projects/something/frontend/vue/src/components/MyComponent.vue"
```

The main goal is NOT expose the local path... /Users/myuser/Projects/something/frontend/vue/src/components/MyComponent.vue

Webpack version: 3.11.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a project with `vue init webpack my-webpack-proj`.

Comment: Did you built the project?

Comment: Yes, I built it and searched the output.

Comment: Do you think it could be due to the aliases?
This is the content of my aliases.config.js 

const path = require('path')
function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, './', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
  '@scss': resolve('src/scss'),
  '@utils': resolve('src/utils'),
};